# Is there a way to determine that a Connection is managed?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, jakarta-ee, connection

I have some legacy JDBC code that is used within an EJB, in this code a call to setAutocommit() is made (which is not allowed for managed transactions, for understandable reasons).

I would like to skip this method call if the code is used within a managed transaction, but let the call remain if used in an un-managed context.

Is there a standardised way to detect if a JDBC Connection object is "managed" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit decent transaction manager does `setAutoCommit(false)` and `setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_XXX)`.

Depending on the JDBC driver and the transaction manager used, you may have some luck with [`getAutoCommit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getAutoCommit%28%29) and/or [`getTransactionIsolation()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getTransactionIsolation%28%29). Determine by testing which values are been used in both cases so that you can learn how to distinguish the one from other.

Comment: Good advice! I eventually decided to just skip the setAutoCommit entirely though, since I realized the code I had would really just be used within a container at the moment anyway, and will hopefully be completely deprecated soon, but your suggestions seems like a good solution would I need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, checking auto commit and transaction isolation was not enough, because they were set to the same value (`false` and `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`, respectively), both when the Connection was provided by Hibernate directly (standalone) and when running inside a JEE container (managed transactions).

As I did not find any other attributes, I ended up using the following code, which checks if the Connection is of type `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7` (or similar).

```java
if (!conn.getAutoCommit()) {
    if (!conn.getClass().getName().startsWith("org.jboss.jca.")) {
        conn.commit();
    }
}
```

I am not happy with this solution, so if anyone has a better idea, please let me know!